# Jupyter notebook ImportError: No module named enum

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I run `jupyter notebook`, I get the error

```
ImportError: No module named enum
```

In plain python, `import enum` works fine.

Python version is 3.8.5. I am using Fedora 32, and jupyter still worked before I upgraded from Fedora 31.

`jupyter --version` says

```
jupyter core     : 4.6.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.3
qtconsole        : 4.7.6
ipython          : 7.16.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.7
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

How can I fix jupyter notebook?

---

From comments :

```
import sys
sys.version_info
```

says

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

I tried `pip install enum34` but `jupyter notebook` still shows the same error after that.

Comment: Is the jupyter notebook Python interpreter the same as the interpreter you're using normally?

Comment: @Tensza How can I check that ?

Comment: `import sys` and then `sys.version_info`, that should tell you what python version it's running. `enum` has existed since 3.4

Comment: @Chase But I can't do that with jupyter, since trying to use jupyter returns that error

Comment: Try `pip install enum34`

Comment: @Meysam I ran that, but it didn't change the error with jupyter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled jupyter notebook and re-intsalled it twice. That made the problem disappear.